# Getting sequence of commands from a client socket

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing a basic server/client dialog where the client sends a command followed by a few arguments.

For example:

```
(<command> <arg1> <arg2>\n<final arg>)
//client input: 
CREATE somefile.txt 19\n
some file text here
```

The server parses the commands, and performs the operation. Here is my problem;the '\n' character implies the rest of the arguments are going to be supplied in the next 'send()'. So in the example, the text of the file comes some time after the first few arguments.

The 'error' here is that if file text is sent to quickly, the two commands seem to be placed in the same buffer.

This occurs in the following example:

```
//INSIDE CLIENT.C:

//INPUT 1: causes trouble
write( sock, command, strlen( command ) );
write( sock, filecontents, strlen( filecontents ) );     

//INPUT 2: works fine
write( sock, command, strlen( command ) );
sleep(1);
write( sock, filecontents, strlen( filecontents ) );     

//INSIDE SERVER.C:
int len = recv(client_socket, args, buffer_size, 0);//get the initial args <CREATE> <FILENAME> <BYTES>
printf("command:%s", args);

//code to parse the command and call relevant method
...
//in the "Create file" method, we wait for the contents of the file
int len = recv( client->client_socket, contents, buffer_size, 0);
printf("contents:%s", contents);
```

Output depending on the amount of time in between client write()s:

```
//OUTPUT 1: without sleep():
//The first recv gets all the data, 
//then the next recv gets the whole message again (from the next client iteration, 
command:CREATE file.txt 19
some file text here
contents:CREATE file.txt 19
some file text here

//OUTPUT 2: with sleep(): 
command:CREATE file.txt 19
contents:some file text here
```

**Goal**:
I need it to look like output 2 everytime. The problem is, I can't control what the client does, so sleep() is not a permanent solution. How should I go about this problem?

**Note**: I'm pretty sure the issue is solvable by changing how recv is handled, and as such I don't think much more code was needed. Let me know if I should post more.

**Edit**: The only thing I know for sure is that the initial command i.e. `CREATE file.txt 89\n` will always end with a '\n' no matter what. If recv() received all the data at once, then I could just read up to the first '\n'. But when this is not the case, and the message (and buffer) is split into two, like in the following example:

```
CASE 1:
int len = recv( client->client_socket, args, buffer_size, 0);
//args == "CREATE file.txt 19\nsome file text here"

CASE 2:
int len = recv( client->client_socket, args, buffer_size, 0);
//args == "CREATE file.txt 19\n"

CASE 3://<--might have made this one up, could not reproduce
int len = recv( client->client_socket, args, buffer_size, 0);
//args == "CREATE file.txt 19\n" <--- this means I have to recv again

int len2 = recv( client->client_socket, args, buffer_size, 0);
//possibilities:
//
//the second recv() might contain:
//args == "CREATE file.txt 19\nsome file text here"
//or
//args == "some file text here"
```

In case 1, all the data is retrieved in the first recv, all the data is in one buffer.
In case 2, the first half is stored in the buffer. Now, in this case I know I need to wait for the rest of the data to arrive. However, by the time it arrives, how will I know if the data in the buffer still contains the "create" section?

```
//I would need something like this:
if(commands still in buffer from recv, and the text file data has arrived)
{
     //then skip over those args, and begin reading form a different index
}
else {
     //read the data from the start.
}
```

But I'm having trouble coming up with a way to do this...does that make sense?

Comment: Network sockets don't work this way. `write` and `recv` are not linked in the sense that `recv` always receives the data of exactly a single call to `write`. You have to implement a message delimiting scheme, e.g. by sending the length of the message in the command.

Comment: @reima Okay, so then my question becomes how do I actually do that? This assignment requires input exactly as shown (without bytes that say how long a command is meant to be). Making an edit, please check it out.

Comment: Well, it looks like the length of the message after the newline is already specified as `<arg2>` in the command.

Comment: @reima Hopefully you can see the issue (that I think) is still present from that edit. How do I know whats still in the buffer, and from where to start (what index) reading the final text contents from?

Comment: `recv` returns the number of bytes it wrote to your buffer. Add that to the offset into the buffer for your next `recv`. Repeat until you have enough data to parse the command. To simplify things, you might want to `recv` one byte at a time until the first newline. Then do as many `recv` as needed to receive the file contents.

Comment: Okay I think I get it, I couldn't reproduce case 3 (I must have made it up) and that was giving me issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't trust the network that much.

As you've found, nothing guarantees a `recv()` will receive just the data of an individual `send()`. There's a lot of buffering involved in the path your bytes go from your `send()` function to the `recv()`, and so no one guarantees you about that.

What I'd advise you - and [*do* advise at University](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1_5JTOBKjEs5w_ZLOt5GN_FGaVI4VRHmVeMLJKKZXSFI/edit#slide=id.g12e70c748_792) :) - is to implement some kind of protocol that uses fixed-length fields to know about variable-length data.

You could, for example, start every message you want to send by sending before 4 bytes indicating how many bytes *of real data* are you going to send, and then the data you want. On your receiver, you first `recv()` with a fixed size of 4 bytes, then allocate a block of memory of as many bytes as that number represents, and lastly you `recv()` that many bytes.

That way you always know how much data to receive, and when to divide it, and the like - at least [as much as the network lets you](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).

Also, don't forget to check `send()` and `recv()` return values, as they may indicate you're still missing some bytes - and retry if needed.

Comment: Oh sneaky links, didn't notice both of them at first. Second one was a fun read, thank you. My issue was ultimately discerning between the command and the data, and you set me on the right track.